# Geting list of all partitons and their names on startup volume

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, volume, disk-partitioning

Using Cocoa, how can I get list of all partitions with their mounted paths and volume names on startup disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `diskutil list -plist` and parse the output.

Comment: This is not a clean cocoa solution, I don't want to run any external, although system, utilities. I believe there must be API for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Believing it doesn't make it so.  `diskutil` uses a private framework called `DiskManagement`.